# Android Error: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'

Tags: java, android

```js
package com.example.user.facefront;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.service.media.CameraPrewarmService;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.hardware.camera2.*;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.MemoryHandler;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

/**
 * Created by user on 2016/2/1.
 */
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public  class  camerafront extends Activity  {
    private  SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;

    private CameraManager manager;
    private  CaptureRequest.Builder builder;
    private CameraDevice cameraDevice;

    private HandlerThread handlerThread;
    private Handler handler;

    private ImageReader imageReader;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camerafront);

        manager=(CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        surfaceView=(SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        holder=surfaceView.getHolder();

        holder.setFixedSize(1280,960);

        holder.addCallback(surfaceViewCallback);
    }
    private  SurfaceHolder.Callback surfaceViewCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

            handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HT");
            handlerThread.start();
            handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
            imageReader=ImageReader.newInstance(1280,960, ImageFormat.RGB_565,3);

            try{
                
                 manager.getCameraIdList();

               
                manager.openCamera("0", DeviceStateCallback, handler);
            }catch (CameraAccessException e){
                Log.e("CameraAccessException",e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            if(cameraDevice != null)
                cameraDevice.close();
        }
    };

    private CameraDevice.StateCallback DeviceStateCallback= new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            try{
                cameraDevice=camera;

                builder.addTarget(holder.getSurface());

                cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(holder.getSurface(),imageReader.getSurface()),CameraCaptureCallback,handler);

            }catch (CameraAccessException e){
                Log.e("CameraAccessException", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {

        }
    };

    private CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CameracaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCaptureProgressed(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, CaptureResult partialResult) {
            super.onCaptureProgressed(session, request, partialResult);
        }
    };

    private CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback CameraCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            try {
                session.setRepeatingRequest(builder.build(), CameracaptureCallback,handler);
            }catch (CameraAccessException e){
                Log.e("CameraAccessException", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

        }
    };


  }
```

If I run the program, I will receive the following error
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I don't know the reason why I got this message, please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Error say "see logs". Did you see it? Where is the log?

Comment: One possibility could be that you have dublicate tags in <application> through your project. Check the manifests of all modules.

Comment: The log just says  "Gradle build finished with 1 error(s)"

Comment: Someone tells me may be of the SDK version does not match

Comment: This is the code in build.gradle(Module.app)
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.facefront"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

}

Comment: and my smart phone sdk version is 21
How can I fix this promblem?